# Using hibernate how to get one record values from first table and get list of records from second table which matching to first table id

Tags: java, sql, json, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 3 tables(tabl1,tbl2,tbl3) as follows. Using Hibernate Criteria iam trying to get data from results but it is not working even i have tried to use Sql query also.

```
tbl1
Id | Number | Column2 | Column3
--------------------------------
1  |  1     | text1   | text11
2  |  2     | text2   | text12
3  |  3     | text3   | text13
4  |  3     | text4   | text14
5  |  2     | text5   | text15

tbl2
Id | tbl1_id| br_id | 
------------------------
1  |  1     | 1  
2  |  2     | 1   
3  |  3     | 3
4  |  3     | 4   
5  |  2     | 2

tbl3
br_id | Column4 | Column5
--------------------------------
1  |text1   | text11
2  |text2   | text12
3  |text3   | text13
4  |text4   | text14
5  |text5   | text15
```

I want data from above table based on `Number` like as follows. Using alias also result is not like as follow

```
{
    "rs": [
        {
            "Column2 ": "text",
            "Column3 ": "text",
             "br_d":[
             {
            "Column4 ": "text",
            "Column5 ": "text",
             },
             {
            "Column4 ": "text",
            "Column5 ": "text",
             }
           ]
        },
        {
            "Column2 ": "Ch",
            "Column3 ": "text",
            "br_d":[
             {
            "Column4 ": "text",
            "Column5 ": "text",
             }
           ]
        },
        {
            "Column2 ": "text",
            "Column2 ": "text",
        }
    ],
    "s": "1"
}
```

I want to get data like above format if anyone knows please help.

Comment: above format is a `JSON`. nothing to do with sql especially. also you don't show what you tried

Comment: It seems like you want to create many-to-many relation. http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many this might help you.

Comment: i have try INNERJOIN but iam getting repeat data,

Comment: @MarkoTaht i have already created One To Many,Many To Many relationship between 3 tables but iam unable to get data as above format.

Comment: With out getting more information on what you have set up. I can say that you can't return JSON from database. You can create a model that has the fields like in JSON and then you return your query result to this model and then you convert it into JSON.

Comment: @MarkoTaht i have created modules and query everything is fine result also coming but instead of coming 3 objects it is coming 5 Objects with duplicate data. Based on 3rd table values are coming duplicate.

Comment: try adding distinct keyword or something. Without the actual SQL query im just guessing here.